# jQuery code won't work on IE8. It works on IE9 and 10

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer-8

Here are some errors from the IE console:

> Unable to get property 'transition' of undefined or null reference
>
> Object doesn't support property or method 'delay'

```
$(function () {
    $('.bubbleInfo').each(function () {
    
        var distance = 0;
        var time = 250;
        var hideDelay = 10;
        var hideDelayTimer = null;
        var beingShown = false;
        var shown = false;
        var trigger = $('.trigger', this);
        var info = $('.popup', this).css('opacity', 0);
    
        $([trigger.get(0), info.get(0)]).mouseover(function () {

            if (hideDelayTimer)
                clearTimeout(hideDelayTimer);
            
            if (beingShown || shown) {
                // don't trigger the animation again
                return;
            } else {
                // reset position of info box
                beingShown = true;
    
                info.css({
                    display: 'block'
                }).animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }, time, 'swing', function() {
                    beingShown = false;
                    shown = true;
                });
            }
          return false;
        }).mouseout(function () {
        
            if (hideDelayTimer)
                clearTimeout(hideDelayTimer);
    
            hideDelayTimer = setTimeout(function () {
                hideDelayTimer = null;
                info.animate({
                    opacity: 0
                }, time, 'swing', function () {
                    shown = false;
                    info.css('display', 'none');
                });
            }, hideDelay);
            return false;
        });
    });
});
```

I really don't know what's wrong with this. I'm not an expert in jQuery.

Comment: Please format your code. It is unreadable.

Comment: @Tarmo - that's an annoying markdown bug... You can't have a list block followed directly by a code block... See my edits to learn how to cope with it... The OP did everything correctly regarding formatting :)

Comment: sorry..i'll try to format it..its my first time posting here.

Comment: @Aldwin - you're fine - don't need to change anything :) It's a weird bug with the markdown engine [so] uses.

Comment: @Aldwin, which version of jQuery are you using? The 2.x branch does not support IE8.

Comment: Yes, I guess that has something to do with it. Your code does not show any `transition` (whatever that is?) and `.delay()`.

Comment: @Lix you *can* have a code block after a list block, but Markdown expects it to be *part of the list* - if you indent 8 instead of 4 it works, or if you just add a dummy non-indented slug.

Comment: @ Frédéric Hamidi, tnx for the reply...i really don't know what version it is..may i know where can i find the version of it? i'm using it on a wordpress site. and i install a jquery updater plugin

Comment: @dollarvar the delay is when you hover a link, their will be a box that will pop out..somewhat like its fading in...i'm not sure if that's the delay..the fading..

Answer (score 1):

Which version of jQuery are you using?

[jQuery's Browser Support page](http://jquery.com/browser-support/) states that jQuery 2.x works on IE 9+, so naturally it won't function properly on IE 8, in which case you'd have to use jQuery 1.x.

If you are using jQuery 1.x, then there's something else going wrong...